# Hash overriding values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this structure of code and for some reason  hash is overrinding hash

```
    audiencias = Documento::Audiencia.obter_audiencias_por_periodo(orgao_id, data_inicial, data_final)
audiencias.each do |audiencia|
  ano = audiencia.dth_audiencia.year
  mes = audiencia.dth_audiencia.month - 1
  dia = audiencia.dth_audiencia.day
  hora = audiencia.dth_audiencia.hour
  situacao = audiencia.pendente?

  calendario_hash['calendario_status'] = {} if calendario_hash['calendario_status'].nil?
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano] = {} if calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano].nil?
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes] = {} if calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes].nil?
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia] = {"pendente"=> situacao} if calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia].nil?
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora] = {} if calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora].nil?

  audiencia = JSON.parse(audiencia.to_json(:only => [:id, :desc_audiencia, :dth_audiencia, :finalizada, :nr_processo_judicial], :include => {:objeto_tramitacao => {:only => [:id, :nr_objeto_tramitacao, :referencia]}, :audiencia_tipo => {:only => [:id, :nm_audiencia_tipo]}}))
  situacao = Documento::Audiencia.find_by_id(audiencia['audiencia']['id']).pendente?
  audiencia['audiencia']['pendente'] = situacao
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora]['audiencias'] = []
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora]['audiencias'] << audiencia['audiencia']
end
```

I want to know if have some way to hash not override other hash in this structure
[EDIT] Example: Day 28 could have different audiências in same hour

```
   2021=>{
    8=>{
        28=>{
            15=>[
                {
                    "id"=>56,
                     Audiência 
                },
                {
                    "id"=>59,
                      Audiência 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hash will obviously override if there is same key present in hash. You're using a loop to generate the hash. In the middle of the loop, the `calendario_status` key is same for all `audiencia`. Also, `ano`, `mes`, `dia` can be same for different `audiencia`. use uniq key.

Comment: it will override i know, but only some values . i want generate a structure like this with all values from audiencias considering day, month , year and day{
    "calendario_status"=>{
        2021=>{
            8=>{
                10=>{
                    16=>{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hash will obviously override if there is same key present in hash. You're using a loop to generate the hash. In the middle of the loop, the `calendario_status` key is same for all `audiencia`. Also, `ano`, `mes`, `dia` can be same for different `audiencia`. use uniq key. I would prefer to do it like this way:

```rb
audiencias.each do |audiencia|
  ano = audiencia.dth_audiencia.year
  mes = audiencia.dth_audiencia.month - 1
  dia = audiencia.dth_audiencia.day
  hora = audiencia.dth_audiencia.hour
  situacao = audiencia.pendente?

  calendario_hash['calendario_status'] ||= {}
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano] ||= {}
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes] ||= {}
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia] ||= {"pendente"=> situacao}
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora] ||= {}

  audiencia = JSON.parse(audiencia.to_json(:only => [:id, :desc_audiencia, :dth_audiencia, :finalizada, :nr_processo_judicial], :include => {:objeto_tramitacao => {:only => [:id, :nr_objeto_tramitacao, :referencia]}, :audiencia_tipo => {:only => [:id, :nm_audiencia_tipo]}}))
  situacao = Documento::Audiencia.find_by_id(audiencia['audiencia']['id']).pendente?
  audiencia['audiencia']['pendente'] = situacao
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora]['audiencias'] ||= []
  calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora]['audiencias'] << audiencia['audiencia']
end
```

This way, we've always a uniq key `audiencia.id` in the hash.

I know you're expecting to override some value as you mentioned in the comment `{ "calendario_status"=>{ 2021=>{ 8=>{ 10=>{ 16=> {}}`.
But think, if in the middle of the expecting hash, `mes` value is same for two `audiencia`, then the  whole `calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes]` will be override, which is not expected, right?

Comment: i need this exactly structure  for my front-end {"calendario_status"=>{2021=>{8=>{10=>{"pendente"=>true, 16=>{}}}}}} have some way to not override and not show id ?

Comment: it will be something like this i guess {123=>{"calendario_status"=>{2021=>{8=>{10=>{"pendente"=>true, 16=>{}}}}}}}

Comment: calendario_hash['calendario_status'][ano][mes] is not expected to be override

Comment: if i have 10 audiencias it have to be 10 audienca there even if with the same ['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora] year, month, day and hour

Comment: Like this structure in post edited

Comment: @Tilipim check the edited answer. Hope it'll solve you're issue

Comment: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in calendario_hash[audiencia.id]['calendario_status'][ano][mes][dia][hora] ||= {}

Comment: @Tilipim Fixed. Please check edited answer. There was an extra `audiencia.id` which I forget to remove